# Stretch a WPF window across two screens

Tags: wpf, multiple-monitors

I am a beginner in WPF. I want my application to stretch across two screens which have the same resolution.
I need a sample code application, because I don't know where I can start.

Thank you

Comment: be carefull as the user may not have both screan setup with the "tops" at the some point. A user can setthe relationship of the screan up in windows however you wish.

Comment: Can you explain me in detail.I didn't understand all you that you have explain to me.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `Screen` class will provide you with information about all the screens. Without having actually done it before, I'd try something like:

```
int windowPosX = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left;
int windowPosY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top;

int windowWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
int windowHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
  if (!s.Primary)
    windowWidth += s.Bounds.Width;

// Set the window's left, top, width and height properties accordingly
```

Comment: Where I put this code.Do you have you a complete example? Thank you

Comment: Put this in the form's `Load` code. As for a complete example: no, I don't have one. But you can easily create it. Just create an empty WPF application, select the main window in the designer, change to the "Events"-tab in the property window, double-click the "Load"-event and put the above code into the generated event handler. In addition to my code above, set the window's location and dimensions using the respective properties.