# Creating window larger than screen size in windows 10?

Tags: wpf

I have an app working on windows 10. And program size is width=1800 and height=900.
So if i run this program on 1600x900 or 1024x768 monitor, then its not showed properly and can't resize it larger than screen.
To make contents size relative is the one of solutions but i want to know way to resize window larger than screen size.
Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would expect that if you've configured your desktop to span both screens, and the window can fit within the bounds of the extended desktop, it should "just work". See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108218/stretch-a-wpf-window-across-two-screens. Unfortunately, since your post lacks a [mcve], or any actionable details really, it's difficult to say what a good solution for you might be. Please improve the question.

Comment: You can easily change a Window' size by setting its Width and/or Height. Then, what do you  intend to accomplish?

Comment: @emoach: "you can easily change" - could you provide steps to do that?  I don't see any menu options for those setting as they apply to windows.

Comment: @end-user I literally mean to set Window.Width and/or Window.Height properties at run time.